# pass string& to class method C++

Tags: c++

Trying to call my StringUtil class to access  createTrimmedString method passing the string reference, string&.

```
--- error: cannot call member function ‘void StringUtil::createTrimmedString(const string&)’ without object
       vehicleRegA = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+201,60));
                                                                                         ^
joinNcfClu.cpp:151:81: error: cannot call member function ‘void StringUtil::createTrimmedString(const string&)’ without object
       vehicleRegB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+261,8));
                                                                                          ^
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "StringUtil.h"

void Inventory::getVehicleResults(ifstream * inFile, stringList& vehicleList,
                               string typeOfVehicle, stringList& miscList, string& vinLine)
{
    int features_max;
    int t_Len;
    int vehicleDataLen;

  //StringUtil S;
    string prevSeqNum;
    if ( typeOfVehicle == "A" )
    {
            features_max = 14;
            Len = 36;
            vehicleDataLen = features_max * t_Len;
            if ( vehicleList.size() == 0 )
            {
                    claSeqNum = vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen,7);
   
                    vehicleRegA = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+57,70));
                    vehicleRegB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+261,8));
       
                    vehicleKey = vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+269,9);
                    actual_veh = vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+289,16);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // 
        }

}

//StringUtil.h

#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <list>

typedef list<string > vehicleList;

class StringUtil
{

public:

   StringUtil()
   {

   };

   ~StringUtil();

   void createTrimmedString(const std::string& vinLine);
    
private:
}


};
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with passing a `string&` and everything to do with the fact that `createTrimmedString` is not a `static` method of the `StringUtil` class. Once you fix this, you might run into a problem where `createTrimmedString` takes its argument by `const` reference and returns `void`, so I'm not sure where you expect the output to go.

Comment: As @NathanPierson says but how about making `StringUtil` a `namespace` rather than a class if it's only going to have static functions ?

Comment: What i was intending to do by using void class method return type  to modify the formal reference parameter string& vinLine in the StringUtil.cpp.

Comment: Added static to StringUtil.h,static string createTrimmedString(string& cluLine);, get different error
StringUtil.h:34:19: note: static std::string StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::string&)
 static string createTrimmedString(string& cluLine);
                   ^   StringUtil.h:no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’
 error: no matching function for call to ‘StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::basic_string<char>)’
custDOB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(cluLine.substr(cluDataLen+261,8));

Answer (score 0):

Since the function you're using requires a instance of the class you would need to something like:

```
StringUtil string_util;
vehicleRegA = string_util.createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+57,70));
vehicleRegB = string_util.createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+261,8));
```

to get what you've got building.

That being said, since the function probably doesn't require any data inside of the `StringUtil` class, I would suggest either making the function static inside of the `StringUtil` class:

```
class StringUtil
{
public:
   StringUtil() {};

   ~StringUtil();

   // just add static to the front here
   static void createTrimmedString(const std::string& vinLine);
    
private:
}
};
```

or, since it looks like that function is the only the class exists for, you could just make it a free function inside of a namespace:

```
namespace StringUtil {
void createTrimmedString(const std::string& vinLine);
}
```

Both of those wouldn't require changing the call to the function at all.

Comment: When i made it static, i got different error 
StringUtil.h:34:19: note: static std::string StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::string&)
 static string createTrimmedString(string& vinLine);
                   ^                                 StringUtil.h:34:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’
joinNcfClu.cpp:151:81: error: no matching function for call to ‘StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::basic_string<char>)’
       custDOB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(cluLine.substr(cluDataLen+261,8));

Comment: I am going to add other methods to StringUtil hence going with class. As you mentioned, it is important to not change the call to function as is existing code

Comment: Sounds good, it looks like that's a different error message so maybe it's worth updating the question or posting a new one?

Answer (score 0):

`In my StringUtil class, i changed static string createTrimmedString(string& vinLine) however i got different error --joinNfClu.cpp:150:81: error: no matching function for call to ‘StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::basic_string<char>)’ custQB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+201,60)); ^ joinNfClu.cpp:150:81: note: candidate is: In file included from joinNcfClu.cpp:4:0: StringUtil.h:34:19: note: static std::string StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::string&) static string createTrimmedString(string& cluLine); ^ StringUtil.h:34:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ joinNcfClu.cpp:151:81: error: no matching function for call to ‘StringUtil::createTrimmedString(std::basic_string<char>)’ custDOB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(cluLine.substr(cluDataLen+261,8)); ^`

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
//StringUtil.h

#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <list>

typedef list<string > vehicleList;

class StringUtil
{

public:

   StringUtil()
   {

   };

   ~StringUtil();

   static string createTrimmedString(string& vinLine);
    
private:
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#include <iostream>
#include "Inventory.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "StringUtil.h"

void Inventory::getVehicleResults(ifstream * inFile, stringList& vehicleList,
                               string typeOfVehicle, stringList& miscList, string& vinLine)
{
    int features_max;
    int t_Len;
    int vehicleDataLen;

  //StringUtil S;
    string prevSeqNum;
    if ( typeOfVehicle == "A" )
    {
            features_max = 14;
            Len = 36;
            vehicleDataLen = features_max * t_Len;
            if ( vehicleList.size() == 0 )
            {
                    claSeqNum = vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen,7);
   
                    vehicleRegA = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+57,70));
                    vehicleRegB = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+261,8));
       
                    vehicleKey = vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+269,9);
                    actual_veh = vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+289,16);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // 
        }

}
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: `static string createTrimmedString(string& vinLine);` should take vinLine by const& or by value

Comment: in StringUtil.h, changed prototype, static string createTrimmedString(const& vinLine); because calling from joinNCl.cpp, vehicleRegA = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+57,70)); which is in 
void Inventory::getVehicleResults(ifstream * inFile, stringList& vehicleList,
                               string typeOfVehicle, stringList& miscList, string& vinLine)

Comment: i got it!. Thanks!!.....needed static string createTrimmedString(const string &cluLine); in StringUtil.h for the joinnfcl.cpp call by ref , vehicleRegA = StringUtil::createTrimmedString(vinLine.substr(vehicleDataLen+57,70));